# How to truncate a string after 5 delimiter in java?

Tags: java

String s = aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-ee-23-xyz;

I need to convert the above string into aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-ee, which means my output should only print words before fifth delimiter. could any help to solve this?

Comment: Google search yielded http://programming.guide/java/nth-occurrence-in-string.html

Comment: You could simply iterate through the string and count how many delimiters you encounter. After counting 5 delimiters, create a substring from the 0th index to the index of the 5th delimiter

Comment: This seems like an homework assignment, please care to elaborate and show some code for us to know that at least you have tried something. Don't expect people to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex:

```
String s = "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-ee-23-xyz";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Output is `aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-ee`

If you have more than just letters you can replace the `\\w` with `[^\\-]` which grabs all characters but the delemiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern and Matcher like this:

```
String s = "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-ee-23-xyz";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((.+?-){4}[^-]+).*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    s = matcher.group(1);
}
```

.* - search all symbols. ? - for lazy work
(.*?-) - search character sequence which end with symbol '-'

{4} - in your result string '-' 4 times

[^-]+ - after you search characters without '-'
.* - another characters after you serch

matcher.group(1) - return first group. This is ((.+?-){4}[^-]+)